# Springboot Kotlin @Pattern annotation ignored

Tags: java, regex, spring, kotlin

I am really desperate to solve this issue. All I want is to validate the input parameter with @Pattern annotation, but it simply ignores it.
The code accepts all the requests coming through.

/hello?name=as2ds -> PASSED
/hello?name=sadasdasdasda -> PASSED

Please guide me.

```java
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import javax.validation.Valid
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern

@RestController
@Validated
class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun getHello(@Valid @RequestParam("name") @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-z]{4}$") name : String) : String {
        return "Hello $name!"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `@Valid` supports annotations directly on the parameter like that. Usually, the `@Pattern` and other validations are on fields of the incoming DTO.

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using and do you have `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency (which you should).

Comment: is it due to ordering of the annotations? Could you try: `@Valid @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+") @RequestParam String myParam`

Comment: I use spring-boot-starter-validation 3.1.1

Comment: Changing the order to ```@Valid @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+") @RequestParam String myParam```, did not help

Comment: Could you try removing the Valid annotation and use Validated on the controller level as shown in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@tericcabrel/validate-request-body-and-parameter-in-spring-boot-53ca77f97fe9)?

Comment: Some other possibility: for some Spring annotations to work in Kotlin, you have to either use the "kotlin-spring" plugin in your build, or set your class and method `open`, to ensure Spring can properly create proxies over your component.

Comment: Spring 3.x went from javax.* to jakarta.* (You are using spring-boot-starter-validation 3.1.1). Change your `Valid` and `Pattern` imports to `jakarta.validation.Valid` and `jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern`

Comment: Thank you @AlexejTimonin !
Changing to jakarta's annotations helped!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Alexej Timonin the problem has been solved.
His comment solved the probelm

> Spring 3.x went from javax.* to jakarta.* (You are using
> spring-boot-starter-validation 3.1.1). Change your Valid and Pattern
> imports to jakarta.validation.Valid and
> jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern